# Navigate to some base BrowserRouter's base route from another BrowserRouter showing "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

While navigating from one `BrowserRouter` to other `BrowserRouter`'s it's showing "Maximum update depth exceeded".

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a > component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either > doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on > every render.

App code

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <BrowserRouter basename="">
        <Navigate to="base-route" />
      </BrowserRouter>
      <BrowserRouter basename="base-route">
        <Router />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first router is unconditionally rendering the `Navigate` component which creates the render looping. Render `Navigate` on a route, e.g. `"/"`, so it is ***conditionally*** called only when the `"/"` path is matched.

Example:

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="base-route" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <BrowserRouter basename="base-route">
        <Router />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

Note that by doing this the second router with the `"/base-route"` path won't be aware of the navigation action that was dispatched and handled by the first router, and won't rerender to display the correct routed content. You can resolve this on the client-side with a small refactor to additionally trigger a page reload.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const BaseRedirect = ({ to, replace }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.location.reload();
  }, []);

  return <Navigate to={to} replace={replace} />;
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<BaseRedirect to="base-route" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <BrowserRouter basename="base-route">
        <Router />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

If you wish to avoid this client-side page reload then you should configure the server to return a 301 response for the first URL to redirect the client, e.g. the browser, to the second URL.